# REST Webservice with HBase, KNOX and NiFi

Tags: web-services, rest, hortonworks-data-platform, apache-nifi, knox-gateway

I'm using Hortonworks and I want to set up a REST webservice. The data is stored in HBase and I want to secure it with KNOX and Ranger.
I'm not sure if it is possible to configure it with NiFi, so I can call the REST API and get data from the HBase (with Hive). It is important, that the connection is secured with KNOX and I can also use Ranger for the data security.

1. Can I use NiFi for it?
2. What is the best solution/architecture to fit the use case?

It would be also great, if you can also add some related advanced informations, so I can go deeper into this subject.

thank you in advanced and best regards
n3

Answer (score 1):

From NiFi's perspective it would only be interacting with your REST service so it would come down to how you authenticate to your REST service. The InvokeHTTP processor can perform basic authentication with a username and password, or can provide certificate information through an SSL context.

Everything to do with Ranger, Knox, and HBase is all hidden behind your REST service.

Comment: Hey Bryan, thank you for your answer. The REST service is confusing me totally because as far as I know there is no standard solution for it. I can use WebHCat to execute queries, but I don't get any results.


I try to setup a REST service with Nifi but it doesn't work. I get the request, but until now I can't send a result with the response. I'm looking for an other way with WebHCat but it is the same problem. Very confusing. Additional I need want to secure the REST service with Knox and Ranger, but it would be great to have a working REST service with a result send as response.

Comment: I think I initially thought you wanted to use NiFi to query an existing REST service, but now I realize you want to build a new REST service. The way you would do this in NiFi is using the HanddleHttpRequest and HandleHttpResponse processors. I'm not sure how you would protect this with Ranger/Knox, but you should be able to return a response. An example REST service that returns the contents of a file is shown in this picture at the bottom: https://github.com/bbende/nifi-streaming-examples/blob/master/nifi-flink-examples/screens/nifi-flink-core.png